# How to measure the size of the text in specific font of specific font size

Tags: html, css, font-size

I would like to do a trimming of the text that I need to display in box on a web page.
The known parameters are Font Family, Font Size, the number of characters to display and the actual text and of course the width of bounding box.

I need to calculate where to trim the source text and where to put "..."

I have an idea but it is not too fast.

If there exist some other way to do the trimming maybe in CSS I would like to know it and I can accept it as a solution too.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot calculate this ahead of time. You need to position the actual text in the browser and measure the output. You can do this off-screen using a negative text-indent if needed.

There are plug-ins for jQuery that can set an ellipsis based on a fixed-sized container with overflow.

See: http://archive.plugins.jquery.com/plugin-tags/ellipsis

Answer (score 0):

So long as you don't need to support older browsers, you could use this simple css:

```
text-overflow:ellipsis;
```

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_text-overflow.asp[enter link description here](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_text-overflow.asp)